# PowerShell: Querying pagefile info for 2008 server

Tags: windows, powershell, wmi, windows-server-2008-r2, pagefile

I'm scripting a check for pagefile status utilizing PowerShell.  On Windows 2000/2003 machines a user can choose between 3 pagefile options via the windows *virtual Memory* dialog:

- Custom Size
- System Managed Size
- No paging file

I can successfully determine which of these options are selected by doing a:

```
$PageFileInfo = Get-WmiObject Win32_PageFileSetting  -ComputerName .
```

- Custom Size - returns `$PageFileInfo.MaximumSize` that is non-zero
- System Managed Size - returns `$PageFileInfo.MaximumSize` that is zero
- No paging file - returns null for `$PageFileInfo`

My issue is that on a Windows 2008 server, there is a 4th option:

- Automatically manage paging file size for all drives

and unfortunately, in this instance `$PageFileInfo` returns `null`, just as if *No Paging file* was selected.

I've attempted utilizing the following, all which return `null` on my test 2008 server when *Automatically manage paging file size for all drives* is selected:

- `Get-WmiObject Win32_PageFileSetting  -ComputerName .`
- `Get-WmiObject Win32_PageFile  -ComputerName .`
- `Get-WmiObject -Query 'SELECT * FROM meta_class WHERE __this ISA
  "Win32_PageFileSetting"'`

How can I determine when `Automatically manage paging file size for all drives` is selected?  am I going about this in a sane manner?

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Automatically managed page file settings are reached via `Win32_ComputerSystem` class. The `Win32_PageFileUsage` class has interesting data as well. A blog article has [more information](http://eaglebcr.wordpress.com/2011/09/29/collect-page-file-server-configurations/) and a neat example.